# pass the clicked value to expose filter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I have the list item 'Articles','Brouchers','Videos' in view tpl page and created expose filter for content type 'Articles','Brouchers','Videos' and expose the filter with auto submit in view page hidden it using css.I want to trigger expose filter when I click the list item.

For expample when I click video I want to pass the value to expose filter and trigger the same thing as when I change to 'video' in expose filter dropdown in drupal 7.

`<ul class="nav nav-justified">
  <li><a href="Articles" class="Articles">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="Brouchers" class="Brouchers">Brouchers</a></li>
  <li><a href="Videos" class="Videos">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="Webniars" class="Webniars">Webniars</a></li>
  </ul>`

Comment: How about using contextual filters instead??

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your view path is `YOURSITENAME/list-test` 
and when you search to choose an expose filter option then your url is 
`YOURSITENAME/list-test?field_list_items_value=Brouchers`

Then create a ul nav like this way...

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">
  <li><a href="list-test?field_list_items_value=Articles" class="Articles">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="list-test?field_list_items_value=Brouchers" class="Brouchers">Brouchers</a></li>
  <li><a href="list-test?field_list_items_value=Videos" class="Videos">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="list-test?field_list_items_value=Webniars" class="Webniars">Webniars</a></li>
</ul>
```

I think this may be useful for you...